# Centering an item within a given ul, li

Tags: html, css, joomla, html-lists

I'm currently building a site in Joomla, and have run into a bit of a snag. I've set a background image for my li elements, however all of the items within the li simply sit as they are, versus being centered within the given element. 
This is the site I'm working on, the list I'm refering to is the one with the video/audio player/blog/media (www.outlawsofhealth.com)

```
<div id="listWrap">
<ul class="mediaWrap">
     <li class="listWrap">  
<!-- youtube player -->
 {youtube}JgN0kqSPL4E&list=PLpJKmZyu1fjM-CzQOB_OrqzZLyIZUeutC&index=1{/youtube}
    </li>
      <li class="listWrap"><!-- audio -->  
            <?php  
                    $show_podcasts=1; 
                    include("podcast/demo/audioMod.php");
           ?>
      </li>

   <li class="listWrap" id="size"> <!-- blog -->       
           <a href="http://www.outlawsofhealth.com/index.php/outlaw-fitness-blog">     <img  id="mediaItem" src="images/mediaMod/blogImg.png" width="225px" /></a>
    </li>
        <li class="listWrap"> <!-- featured mediua -->          
<!-- <a href="http://localhost/outlaws/index.php/featured-media"></a> this link left intentionally broken as section is blank -->
                <img id="mediaItem" class="img-rounded" src="images/mediaMod/mediaImg.png" height="" width="225px">
        </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and the css I'm currently using...

```
<style type="text/css">
#listWrap{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:inline;
padding-bottom:45px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#modAudio{
width:225px;
}
ul.mediaWrap{
display:inline;
}
li.listWrap{
background-image:url('images/mediaMod/mediaBG.png');
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
height:161px;
width:258px;
}
ul.listWrap li.listWrap{
list-style:none;
width:225px;
}
#youtubeAlign{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#mediaItem{

}
</style>
```

Any help in getting the elements within the li centered, would be appreciated.

EDIT: I believe I've fixed my problem, by adding 
    #mediaItem{
    position:absolute;
    Top:597px;
    left:579px; 
    }

to each item, it shifts them accordingly

Comment: You are using the same id `#mediaItem` twice.  Id's should be unique on a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the content vertically, try:

```
li.listWrap{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:161px;
    line-height: 161px;
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to center the contents of the Li within it's element. So the UL is in the proper position, it's the items within the LI that need it. (they're currently aligned to the top)

Comment: So you want the items within each `li` to be aligned in the middle vertically? and left justified (flush left)?

Comment: I think I got it, had to add a custom class, and apply a position:absolute to it.

Comment: You probably don't need absolute positioning.  See updated answer.

Comment: You might want to look at display:block or table-cell, height:1em or whatever fits your content, and margin:auto 0 (browsers will handle auto margins to fill in the vertical space)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the child items to just be horizontally aligned to the center, you could try this CSS:

```
li.listWrap{
    text-align:center;
}
```

However, if you want to vertically align the children too...well, it changes some of the spacing around the list items, unfortunately, but this technically gives you what you want:

```
li.listWrap{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I hope this helps you out a bit. Good luck!